# What are the right mathematical tools / language to analyse complex networks over time?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, applied-mathematics, network-theory, complex-networks

In [this article about human physiology as a complex network](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphys.2020.598694/full) the authors say that:

> "Lacking adequate analytic tools and a theoretical framework to probe
> interactions within and among diverse physiological systems, current
> approaches focus on inferring properties of time-varying
> interactions—namely strength, direction, and functional form—from
> time-locked recordings of physiological observables."

and further:

> The characterization of interactions between physiological systems
> faces several challenges:
>
> • We often do not know exactly the systems’
> equations of motion;
>
> • We lack knowledge as to how to merge/combine
> these equations (e.g., due to the issue of time-scale matching);
>
> • We may have insufficient knowledge about relevant structural connections;
> • We may not have direct access to interactions between systems (e.g.,
> via probing).

Image taken from the above article, where each node corresponds to a human organ and connections between organs represent time varying "connections":

[image: Image taken from the above article, where each node corresponds to a human organ and connections between organs represent time varying "connections"]

Are there tools of complex networks from mathematical point of view which might be suited for the case written above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may well be suitable proprietary tools, but if you prefer open source, you might try [Cytoscape.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoscape)

> Cytoscape is an open source software platform for visualizing
> molecular interaction networks and biological pathways and integrating
> these networks with annotations, gene expression profiles and other
> state data.

This [Google Scholar list](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11328366010452110668) gives you an overview of publications that use this tool.